Why are particles represented by plane waves instead of spherical waves?
Why are particles represented by plane waves instead of spherical waves?
Quantum field theory is based on the theory of plane waves, which simplifies particles into a quasi plane wave. For example, in quantum field theory, particles generated by the generation operator, particles annihilated by the annihilation operator, or particles excited at a certain point are actually plane waves emitted from that point, and the direction of these plane waves is arbitrary (the direction of momentum is arbitrary). But in fact, the solutions of Schrödinger equation and Dirac equation can be spherical waves. Here, spherical waves refer to waves that have a factor of $1/r^2$ along their propagation distance. As waves, there are actually lagging waves and leading waves, both of which are spherical waves, right?

If we care about the angular momentum, we would use spherical waves too. This is standard to scattering theory with the name partial wave analysis, and it is simply assumed of QFT that the student can perform this change of basis by themselves. So, yes, you can just work with spherical waves as the definition of particles too. Note that if there is a Coulomb potential, then the usual partial wave analysis will fail, and you need to upgrade to Coulomb wavefunctions.

In principle, one could decide to decompose a free scalar field in terms of a superposition of "natural" solutions to the wave equation in spherical coordinates, rather than Cartesian.  These "natural" solutions would basically be separable solutions to the Helmholtz equation, which involve spherical Bessel functions and spherical harmonics.  One could then perform the usual sort of canonical quantization procedure, promoting each independent spherical mode to an independent harmonic oscillator, each mode with its own raising and lowering operator.  The process would be basically the same as the typical quantization in terms of plane waves, which are the analogous separable solutions in Cartesian coordinates.
But if nothing else this sounds much more mathematically complicated than the usual decomposition into plane waves.  Fourier analysis is relatively easy compared to Bessel functions.

Right, solutions to the Helmholtz equation can be expanded in any number of orthogonal families of functions. Any of these can be quantized.

But are these solutions eigenstates of the hamiltonian?

@PatoGalmarini I think the answer is always yes in the free-field case. At least this is true for the EM field.

Fourier-Bessel analysis is still Fourier analysis~

Forget particles. Fields can be expressed as linear combinations of spatial modes. Quantum field theory tells us that the amplitudes of the spatial modes are quantized. The decomposition of the field is not unique. It can be decomposed as plane waves or spherical waves. Either way the excitations of the modes are quantized. Forget particles.
